# Convert pre-IEEE-754 C++ floating-point numbers to/from C#

Tags: c#, c++, floating-point, ieee-754

Before .Net, before math coprocessors, before IEEE-574, Microsoft defined a bit pattern for floating-point numbers. Old versions of the C++ compiler happily used that definition.

I am writing a C# app that needs to read/write such floating-point numbers in a file. How can I do the conversions between the 2 bit formats? I need conversion methods in both directions.

This app is going to run in a PocketPC/WinCE environment.

Changing the structure of the file is out-of-scope for this project.

Is there a C++ compiler option that instructs it to use the old FP format? That would be ideal. I could then exchange data between the C# code and C++ code by using a null-terminated text string, and the C++ methods would be simple wrappers around sprintf and atof functions.

At the very least, I'm hoping someone can reply with the bit definitions for the old FP format, so I can put together a low-level bit manipulation algorithm if necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: Could it have been this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Binary_Format?

Answer (score 3):

I followed the bread crumbs from Johannes Rössel's [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Binary_Format) and found a Python implementation that shouldn't be too hard to translate: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_thread/thread/42150ccc20a1d8d5/4aadc71be8aeddbe

Here's the documentation of the format from Bengt Richter in that link:

> According to an old MASM 5.0 programmer's guide, there was a Microsoft Binary format 
>   for encoding real numbers, both short (32 bits) and long (64 bits).
>
> There were 3 parts:
>
> 1. Biased 8-bit exponent in the highest byte (last in the little-endian view we've been using) 
>      It says the bias is 0x81 for short numbers and 0x401 for long, but I'm not sure where that lines up. 
>      I just got there by experimentation.
> 2. Sign bit (0 for +, 1 for -) in upper bit of second highest byte.
> 3. All except the first set bit of the mantissa in the remaining 7 bits of the second highest byte, 
>      and the rest of the bytes. And since the most signficant bit for non-zero numbers is 1, it 
>      is not represented. But if if were, it would share the same bit position where the sign is 
>      (that's why I or-ed it in there to complete the actual mantissa).
>
> MASM also supported a 10-byte format similar to IEEE. I didn't see anything in that section 
>   on NaNs and INFs.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Johannes's answer, you can go to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140520 to download the source code for a conversion .dll from mbf to IEEE.

EDIT: Actually, that isn't helpful for you. But the actual MBF format is documented here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/35826:

```
  -------------------------------------------------
 |              |    |                             |
 |8 Bit Exponent|Sign|   55 Bit Mantissa           |
 |              | Bit|                             |
  -------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That link says that the source code is indeed available, but it requires the old version of the C++ compiler for proper storage of the FP variables. And I can't use the DLL for obvious reasons: this is supposed to run on a PocketPC/WinCE platform.

Comment: The Microsoft link leaves out important details, like the bias of the exponent and whether there's an implied "1" bit at the top of the mantissa.

Comment: @Mark, who would care about that? :) And yes, I upvoted your post.

Comment: @Richard: if you have access to MSDN subscriber downloads, you can get an old MSC compiler, Visual C++ 1.52 or 2.0, that may support the functions in question (`_fmsbintoieee()` and friends). They might even have source for the functions provided. I don't know for sure that they'll be useful, but it might be worth a look if you have access to them anyway.